# Container (lookup? dictionary?) for storing key->2x value pairs in C# to persist temporary grid value changes

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a grid containing calculated columns which the user can edit. I don't want to actually commit the changes until the user choses do to so. Right now the edit event fires on the unbound column and re-calculates it to the default, I want it to persist until they chose to commit the changes (or refresh the entire grid).

My event fires on change with an arg telling me they changed the value for a single cycle, then right away the next cycle it changes that value to the default calculated.

I am totally open to another solution to the above, but my thought on how to accomplish is as such:

Create a lookup table based on the row's guid which contains the two possibly changed cells. When the grid tries to update itself I'll check against this lookup to see if there's a pending change and use that one if so, elsewise just use the default.

Creating this object in JSON seems pretty straight forward, but I don't know the best way to create in C# without creating annoying custom objects.

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    {
      date: 7/1/13,
      time: 12pm
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    {
      date: 7/3/13,
      time: 1pm
    }
  }
]
```

In the above example if the row's ID was 1 or 2 the grid would use those values for date/time, elsewise use the default calculate values.

How can I create this structure with easy lookup abilities in C#? At first I was trying to use a Lookup with the following:

```
private Lookup<Guid, Dictionary<string, string>> pendingChanges;
pendingChanges = new Lookup<Guid, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

But it seems Lookups are not intended for this use as I can't create an empty one, nor can I easily add/remove elements from them as needed.

1. How do I create the ability to look up values from a table which has a guid -> dictionary(string,string)

Comment: Personally I think `Lookup<Guid, Dictionary<string, string>>` is more annoying than a custom class

Comment: @ScottChamberlain hah I think you're right... just got done writing it, probably works better this way anyway. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just rolling my own class for this per Scott's suggestion, and incase anyone is curious (or has change suggestions) figured I'd supply the class here...

```
    protected class PendingChanges
    {
        protected class PendingChange
        {
            public Guid punchId { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public string Time { get; set; }
        }

        private List<PendingChange> pendingChanges;

        public PendingChanges()
        {
            pendingChanges = new List<PendingChange>();
        }

        public void Add(Guid guid, DateTime date)
        {
            foreach (PendingChange change in pendingChanges)
            {
                // Exists in table
                if (change.punchId == guid)
                {
                    change.Date = date;
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Record doens't exist, add it
            PendingChange newChange = new PendingChange();
            newChange.punchId = guid;
            newChange.Date = date;
            pendingChanges.Add(newChange);
        }

        public void Add(Guid guid, string time)
        {
            foreach (PendingChange change in pendingChanges)
            {
                // Exists in table
                if (change.punchId == guid)
                {
                    change.Time = time;
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Record doens't exist, add it
            PendingChange newChange = new PendingChange();
            newChange.punchId = guid;
            newChange.Time = time;
            pendingChanges.Add(newChange);
        }

        public DateTime? LookupDate(Guid guid)
        {
            foreach (PendingChange change in pendingChanges)
            {
                if (change.punchId == guid)
                {
                    return change.Date;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public string LookupTime(Guid guid)
        {
            foreach (PendingChange change in pendingChanges)
            {
                if (change.punchId == guid)
                {
                    return change.Time;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public void Delete(Guid guid)
        {
            foreach (PendingChange change in pendingChanges)
            {
                if (change.punchId == guid)
                {
                    pendingChanges.Remove(change);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Scott said, I think you need a custom class or struct for this. Then you can make a list/dictionary/collection/hash or something of that class or struct.

```
    class DataCell
    {
        // constructor requires a value
        public DataCell(string _originalValue)
        {
            OriginalValue = _originalValue;
        } 

        public int Guid; // unique identifier for each cell
        public string OriginalValue; // starting value  
        public string NewValue; // user hasn't entered this yet
        public bool PendingChange = false; // this is the flag you'll check 
        public string DisplayValue // if flagged, show new value, otherwise show original
        {
            get
            {
                if (PendingChange)
                    return NewValue;
                else
                    return OriginalValue;
            }
            set
            {
                NewValue = value;
                PendingChange = true;
            }
        }

        public void ApplyChange()
        {
            // overwrite the OriginalValue because that's what we write to disk later
            OriginalValue = NewValue;
            PendingChange = false;
        }

        public void UndoChange()
        {
            // turn off the flag to stop showing a new value
            PendingChange = false;
        }


    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // now create a dictionary of these things. 
        Dictionary<string, DataCell> myDataTable = new Dictionary<string, DataCell>();

        // take an excel style name like F3
        myDataTable.Add("F3", new DataCell("steve"));

    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Shawn but I already implemented a class per my answer here that fits my needs better. Definitely a good call to roll my own here though